# Group by clause returning more than one row

Tags: sql, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have an assignment that requires this query:
Write a SELECT statement that returns one row for each customer that has an existing order. Include these columns: The EmailAddress from the Customers table, the sum of purchases from the orderitems table (quantity * price) and the sum of discounts from the orderitems table (discountAmount * quantity). Sort the result set in descending sequence by the item price total for each customer.

There is no common column between the Customers Table or the OrderItems table, so I did a 3-table join. Using the orders table.I ended up with this code:

```
SELECT EmailAddress, SUM(ItemPrice)*Quantity AS TotalSum, SUM(DiscountAmount)*Quantity AS     TotalDiscount
FROM Customers JOIN Orders
ON Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID
JOIN OrderItems ON Orders.OrderID = OrderItems.OrderID
GROUP BY EmailAddress, ItemPrice, Quantity
ORDER BY TotalSum DESC;
```

However, it is returning more than 1 row per email address if they had multiple orders, when there should only be 1 row per customer. I'm not sure why multiple rows are returned.

Comment: I tried grouping just by email address and I got errors saying that "ItemPrice" and "Quantity" were invalid in the select list because they were not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.   What is the solution to that without including them in the Group By clause?

Answer (score 2):

This query should provide the right output. It seems you want to group by email address so the numbers are by email alone, and then adjustments were made to have the quantity within the aggregations.

```
SELECT
    EmailAddress,
    SUM(ItemPrice * Quantity) AS TotalSum,
    SUM(DiscountAmount * Quantity) AS TotalDiscount
FROM Customers
    JOIN Orders
        ON Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID
    JOIN OrderItems
        ON Orders.OrderID = OrderItems.OrderID
GROUP BY EmailAddress
ORDER BY TotalSum DESC;
```

Comment: Yes thank you!  That was exactly what I needed.  So it was just the () no in the right place in the select statement that was giving me errors.  Great!

Comment: I didn't even realize that was a syntax error. I just edited my own answer with a slightly different approach using a subquery, but this is far cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

The reason (likely) that you're getting multiple rows is because you're grouping by three different columns: email, item price, and quantity. If the same email appears twice, but the item price for each one is different, than it will return multiple rows. This is because SQL first groups by email address, then groups by item price, and then quantity. Any rows with a different combination of these 3 will be treated as their own group.

If you need one row per customer, just limit your group by to email address. That will return the customer's email, along with the total sum of all of their purchases, and the total discounts for that customer as well.

**EDIT** I believe the error you are receiving is because you are trying to sum the item price of all rows, and then multiply it by a single quantity. You can see logically why that doesn't make sense, if you're trying to group them. I think the best way to handle that is to make a subquery, that selects all rows and returns the email address, sum, and discount. Once you have this subquery, you can group it after.

Try this as your subquery:

```
SELECT EmailAddress, ItemPrice * Quantity AS orderSum, DiscountAmount * Quantity AS discount
FROM customers 
    JOIN orders ON customers.customerid = orders.customerid
    JOIN orderitems ON orders.orderid = orderitems.orderid
```

If it helps you to run this first to visualize what this is returning, go ahead. This returns all individual rows with the information you require. All that's left is to group and sum them:

```
SELECT EmailAddress, SUM(orderSum) AS totalSum, SUM(discount) AS totalDiscount
FROM (
    SELECT EmailAddress, ItemPrice * Quantity AS orderSum, DiscountAmount * Quantity AS discount
    FROM customers 
        JOIN orders ON customers.customerid = orders.customerid
        JOIN orderitems ON orders.orderid = orderitems.orderid
    ) t
GROUP BY EmailAddress
ORDER BY totalSum DESC
```